# How to set localStorage value on document element value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm beginner of Typescript and Javascript. I would like to set localStorage value on document element's value.

I wrote this code in TypeScript. But I think it's verbose description. Can I make it more shorter code?

```
let colorEelement = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('color');
let color = localStorage.getItem('color');
if(color == null) color = "";
colorEelement.value = color;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you  can wrap the if condition in one line

```
let colorEelement = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('color');
colorEelement.value = localStorage.getItem('color') || ""
```

Comment: Thank you! It's nice! I didn't know this way `localStorage.getItem('color') || ""` and now I found we can write it a line `(<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('color')).value = localStorage.getItem('color') || ""
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like null coalescing in C#.

```
let colorEelement = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('color');
let color = localStorage.getItem('color') ? localStorage.getItem('color') : "";
```